# Creating guice provider with caching

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, guice

I am trying to understand @singleton vs caching in guice

I have a provider. This will give me firefoxoption.This will do lot of json parsing and some heavy stuff

```
@Singleton
public class FirefoxOptionsProvider extends AbstractModule {

  @Provides
  @Named("FirefoxOptionsProvider")
  @Singleton
  public FirefoxOptions getFireFoxOptions(FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary, Gson gson) {
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        fireFoxOptions.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", false); // bydefault it is false
        firefoxOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);  
        //some costly operation like json parsing and setting firefox options
        return firefoxOptions;
}
```

I am calling this method as below

```
@Log4j2
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class FirefoxDriverSetup {
    private FirefoxOptionsProvider firefoxOptionsProvider;

    public WebDriver getWebdriver() {

        fireFoxOptions.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
        return new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
    }
}
```

My Assumption

Does my original singleton `fireFoxOptions` instance get modified when i do  `fireFoxOptions.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);` inside `getWebdriver()`

If so when i call `getWebdriver()` next time it will return `fireFoxOptions` with `fireFoxOptions.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);` because last time I modified this singleton object

Question:

Is it possible to cache all the internal processing of `getFireFoxOptions()` and return me new `getFireFoxOptions`  everytime  so that always i get new instance of  `fireFoxOptions`  with default setup fireFoxOptions.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", false);   without computing it each time

Comment: Why do you inject a module? Please keep your head (and ours too) sane by having a module separated from your providers.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should directly call FirefoxOptionsProvider.getFireFoxOptions() from "getWebdriver()" instead of injecting it ?

Comment: I mean that `@Singleton` (and injecting it) and `extends AbstractModule` on the same class are introducing headaches that no one wants. Also, you say that you call `getFireFoxOptions(FirefoxBinary, Gson)` "as follows", but I don't see it in your code. I believe that you have to take a step back and really understand what dependency injection is and start using Guice with smaller examples.

Comment: Hi I didn't use this "getFireFoxOptions(FirefoxBinary, Gson) " . I wrongly understood you are suggesting to use like this  "getFireFoxOptions(FirefoxBinary, Gson) "   . I try to read about this part .   @Singleton (and injecting it) and extends AbstractModule.